# regex search in github enterprise across thousands of repos

Tags: github, search, github-enterprise

The company I work for uses github enterprise.

React is supplied by the main repo, but I am suspicious hundreds of sub-repos use react in `dependencies` instead of `dev-dependencies`, which is bloating bundle size.

To investigate this, I was thinking of using github search, with regex , so I can filter out all the cases where react is in the correct `dev-dependencies`, but regex is not supported.

I found [this tool](https://grep.app/) which is amazing, but works only for public repos.

Any ideas of how to scan throguh all these repos without cloning each one?

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you're referencing `package.json`'s `dev-dependencies` key, correct? Why would you elect use RegExp on a structured document instead of using a proper JSON parser in a loop on each repository's respective root `package.json` file?

Comment: because I dont want to download thousands of repos. If I did, I could just grep them, or json parse. any idea how to that without downloading everything? github api maybe?